# Time difference to hh/mm/ss conversion

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will convert the difference in time in any given day to HH MM SS.

```
Sub timefind()

Dim eDate As Date

Dim StartDate As Date

Dim mHours As Long, mMinutes As Long, mSeconds As Double

'Dim iValue As Variant

Dim wb1 As Workbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim ws1lastrow As Double

Dim tymval As Double

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Time_Comparison.xlsm")

Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Input")

Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("Dashboard")

Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

ws1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
ws1.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Time"
ws1.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Hours"
ws1.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Minutes"
ws1.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Seconds"

ws1lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

StartDate = ws1.Cells(2, 2).Value

For tymval = 2 To ws1lastrow

    Set curCell = ws1.Cells(tymval, 1)

    Set nextCell = ws1.Cells(tymval, 1).Offset(1, 0)

    If nextCell.Value <> curCell.Value Then

    eDate = ws1.Cells(tymval, 1).Offset(0, 1)
    'to hours
    ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate) / (60 * 60)
    ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) = Int(ws1.Cells(tymval, 3))

    'to Minutes
    ws1.Cells(tymval, 4) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate) / 60 - ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) * 60
    ws1.Cells(tymval, 4) = Int(ws1.Cells(tymval, 4))

    'to seconds
    ws1.Cells(tymval, 5) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate) / 60 - ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) * 60 - ws1.Cells(tymval, 4)
    ws1.Cells(tymval, 5) = ws1.Cells(tymval, 5) * 60

    StartDate = ws1.Cells(tymval, 1).Offset(1, 1)

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Now the new requirement is, if the minutes is <=30 the minutes should be considered as 30 minutes and if the minutes is >30 it should be considered as 60 minutes and added to the hour.
How to do it.

If nextCell.Value <> curCell.Value Then

```
eDate = ws1.Cells(tymval, 1).Offset(0, 1)

ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate) / (60 * 60)
ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) = Int(ws1.Cells(tymval, 3))

ws1.Cells(tymval, 4) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate) / 60 - ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) * 60
ws1.Cells(tymval, 4) = Int(ws1.Cells(tymval, 4))

If ws1.Cells(tymval, 4).Value <= "30" Then
ws1.Cells(tymval, 4).Value = "30"
ws1.Cells(tymval, 4) = Int(ws1.Cells(tymval, 4))

ElseIf ws1.Cells(tymval, 4).Value > "30" Then
ws1.Cells(tymval, 4).Value = "00"
ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) = ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) + 1
ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) = Int(ws1.Cells(tymval, 3))

End If

ws1.Cells(tymval, 5) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate) / 60 - ws1.Cells(tymval, 3) * 60 - ws1.Cells(tymval, 4)
ws1.Cells(tymval, 5) = ws1.Cells(tymval, 5) * 60

ws1.Cells(tymval, 6) = DateDiff("s", StartDate, eDate)

StartDate = ws1.Cells(tymval, 1).Offset(1, 1)
```

Comment: `DateDiff` has arguments for the type of difference you wish to calculate.  What have you tried for the new requirement?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I tried if statement to check whether the converted minute is <=30 or >30, based on that i am setting the hours and minutes. But it is not working as expected. Can you please help/guide regarding this issue

Comment: Add what you've tried to the code you've posted.

Comment: @Nathan i tried to update the post but there seems to be error. Any other way

Comment: Add it in a comment maybe?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav please check, i have added as you requested.

Comment: I dont think you need the `"`'s around the value in this line `ws1.Cells(tymval, 4).Value > "30"`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ok, i have issues when converting in seconds, can you help

Comment: Try `ws1.Cells(tymval, 4).Value > 30`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UDF which I have used for testing. It will be easy to integrate it in your code once is perfected.

```
Function TryDate(Sdate As Date, Edate As Date) As Double

    Dim Fun As Double

    Fun = (Edate - Sdate) * 24
    If Fun - Int(Fun) > 0.5000001 Then Fun = Int(-Fun) * -1
    TryDate = Fun * 60
End Function
```

Call it from the worksheet like `=TryDate(A2, A3)` where A2 has the start time in date/time format and A3 the end time.

The result will be rounded to the full next hour if the minutes are more than 30. It will be expressed in minutes otherwise, including decimals of minutes. You say you want seconds instead. This can be accomplished by this modification.

```
Function TryDate(Sdate As Date, Edate As Date) As Double

    Dim Fun As Double

    Fun = (Edate - Sdate) * 24

    If Fun - Int(Fun) > 0.5000001 Then
        Fun = Int(-Fun) * -60
    Else
        Fun = Int(Fun * 60 * 60)
    End If
    TryDate = Fun
End Function
```

Note that the 0.0000001 added to 0.5 is a value of less than a second, required because VBA wouldn't interpret 30 minutes as 0.5 hours. The addition ensures that 30 minutes will not be rounded up.

Comment: Are you sure that's what he wants? I'm finding it rounds down if less than one hour. eg  `11:59` - `11:00` --> 0

Comment: @Ron, i want to convert the minutes to hour if minutes is greater than 30 and if the minutes is less than or = 30 then minutes to 30. Also want to convert the difference to seconds also

Comment: @santosh That's why I didn't think this answer would work for you. And with no examples of input/desired output in your question, I am loathe to contribute anything.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I tested before posting and found that it rounded up/down.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld on re-testing I find that the rounding doesn't work reliably. There appears to be no fixed rule. I suspect that the function isn't supposed to round and shall revise my answer - anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines

```
Function RoundUpTime(t As Date) As Date

If Minute(t) < 30 Then
    RoundUpTime = TimeSerial(Hour(t), 30, 0)
ElseIf Minute(t) > 30 Then
    RoundUpTime = TimeSerial(Hour(t) + 1, 0, 0)
End If

End Function
```